# zero's for odd and $\pm 1$ for even. Or $\pm 1$ for odd and zero's for even

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients, real-numbers

What is the formula of the real function $f$ that satisfies

\begin{equation}
\sum^{n}_{k=0}{f}=1+0+(-1)+0+1+0+(-1)+0+\cdots
\end{equation}

or 
\begin{equation}
\sum^{n}_{k=0}{f}=0+1+0+(-1)+0+1+0+(-1)+\cdots
\end{equation}
I found here : [Does there exist a function which equals $0$ for odd inputs and $1$ for even inputs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902304/does-there-exist-a-function-which-equals-0-for-odd-inputs-and-1-for-even-inp) a real function that equals $0$ for odd inputs of $k$ and $1$ for even inputs.

I need the first summation. The second summation comes from  the first.

Comment: What do you mean a real function?  You have only defined the values on the integers.  All the techniques in the linked question apply to your function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the frequency and amplitude of a sine or cosine function.
$$\cos(\pi n/2)$$

Comment: The best answer is yours @trisct . This function $\cos(n\pi /2)$ satisfies the first sum, the function that satisfies the second sum is  $\sin(n\pi /2)$ or equiv. $\cos((n-1)\pi /2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(n)=\begin {cases}1&n\equiv 0 \pmod 4\\-1&n \equiv 2 \pmod 4\\0&\text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$
(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}(-1)^\frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}.
$$

Comment: This gives $-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1$ for $n=0,1,2,...10$.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is what I've got for the first summation

\begin{equation}
(k+1)^3-4 \left\lfloor \frac{1}{4} \Big((k+1)^3+\alpha\Big)\right\rfloor,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha\in [1,3)$ is arbitrary. For the last sum, I replace $k$ with $k-1$ to get

\begin{equation}
k^3-4 \bigg\lfloor \frac{1}{4} \big(k^3+\alpha\big)\bigg\rfloor,\qquad \alpha\in [1,3).
\end{equation}